# Problem with downloading pcap capture from Cisco ASA

Tags: cisco-asa, pcap

There is a problem with downloading pcap capture from Cisco ASA 5520 from `https://<ip_of_asa>/admin/capture/<capture_name>/pcap` - an empty file with size 24 bytes is downloaded while `https://<ip_of_asa>/admin/capture/<capture_name>` (without `pcap` in url) shows captured packets fine. The problem started when ASA memory usage was at high level. Now it is back to normal but capture download still fails. The capture was removed and a new one created - this didn't help. I've already faced this problem before and in that case it was resolved after ASA restart. In this case ASA reboot is not an option. Is there a way to resolve this issue without reboot?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Comment: This issue was finally resolved after ASA reboot. At the time when the question was asked a reboot was not possible so it not really an answer. But I'll probably have to add that as an answer.

Comment: Please do. We get a lot of questions with no accepted answers popping up all the time. Users complain that we just see the same questions over and over, so I'm trying to clear the backlog of the year. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved after ASA reboot. Not a real answer since the question was about a fix without reboot. Adding it not to leave the question hanging unaccepted.

Answer (score 3):

As a workaround, it looks like you can manually copy the capture via CLI to any of the normal destinations: https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/asa/asa82/command/reference/cmd_ref/c4.html#wp2144072

This means you should also be able to SCP it off the ASA, if you can't push it to HTTP/FTP/TFTP via the copy command. Here's a good post on using SCP if you haven't before: 
https://thestupidengineer.wordpress.com/2015/04/01/scp-file-to-asa/

You can download Putty's SCP client if you don't have a 'Nix box to use.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. While this a valid solution, I can't use it since I don't have console access to ASA. It is possible to ask colleagues to use such method once or twice but capture needs to be downloaded periodically. The only way for me right now is to restore download via https.

Comment: @AndreyGrachev, I don't understand why you think that you must have console access to the ASA. SCP works over the network, and you should be able to telnet or SSH into the ASA. In fact, it is recommended that you actually disable the HTTP and HTTPS servers in your ASA.

Comment: @RonMaupin, sorry, under console access I actually meant CLI (telnet or SSH) - don't have any of that. HTTP is currently used because there is some automated processing done by downloading the capture periodically.

Comment: @AndreyGrachev, if you do not have CLI access to the ASA, then I do not understand how you think you can resolve a problem on it. For a question to be on-topic here, you must have direct control. Also, it sounds like your capture/processing is really a kludge. There may be better ways to do what you want. You can set up a logging server, and the ASA can automatically send to it on its own, then you can take data from the server at your leisure.

Comment: It sounds like you need to configure NetFlow and have a NetFlow server. You seem to be using the wrong tool for the job. In any case, we would need to see the full (sanitized) ASA configuration.

Comment: @RonMaupin, I can ask my colleagues to execute the commands via CLI but this can't be used to obtain capture as this has to be done regularly. Basically what I need is to get HTTPS download working without reboot (reboot will be done at some point after required approvals are obtained). I would also like to find out if such behavior with HTTPS is a bug or a feature. A logging server doesn't seem to be an option because capture is required to get content of the payload being sent. *had to delete the commnet and add it again to correct misprints

Comment: NetFlow will continually capture the packets and send them to a NetFlow server. This is a tool built into your ASA. You can then query the server on your regular basis. What you have sounds like it was designed by server people who do not understand the networking tools available. To a web developer, everything looks like a web page. If you want to capture traffic on a network device, we have tools designed to do exactly that. In any case, we cannot simply guess if there is a configuration problem with your ASA unless you give us its current configuration.

Comment: @RonMaupin, I will look into NetFlow option - didn't know about it, thank you. As for ASA configuration - it is standard for the capture and I'm sure there is nothing wrong with config itself as we already had similar issue before and it was resolved after ASA reboot.

Comment: If the HTTPS download really is a must, you probably want to open a TAC case. The bug list for "capture" on ASAs is a mile long: https://bst.cloudapps.cisco.com/bugsearch/search?kw=capture&pf=prdNm&pfVal=279513386&sb=anfr